# Images with https in email URL not showing up on iPhone

Tags: iphone, image, email, https

We have a software sending out emails with images. The URL of the images starts with https://. For example: `<img src="https://www.url.com/image.png" />`.
Opening the email in Outlook on Windows 10 shows the image.
Opening the email in the native mail app on iPhone does *not*.

If we change to http://. For example:`<img src="http://www.url.com/image.png" />` it shows in both Outlook on Windows 10 AND in the native mail app on iPhone.

In the first example a request for the image does not even show up in Apache's access.log when the iPhone is opening the email.

Does anyone have a clue to why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the code where a character was missing.

Comment: I just had the same issue these days. No character missing as it seems for me. Works everywhere (Gmail, Web, Android) but IOS. How did you fix it? What was the character missing?

Comment: Also other images as using the google logo works. It just our image host as it seems. IOS Blocks it or idk.